# Prevent addRule from stripping !important

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I am trying to make a jQuery plug-in that injects CSS rules onto the page. I am using `addRule` and `insertRule`.  For some reason, `addRule` strips out `!important` from any rules you pass to it. Is there a way I can prevent it from doing so or a flag I can send to the function to mark the rule as important? I looked at the [documentation for addRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but there was no mention of !important declarations.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
var sheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1];
sheet.addRule('body','color: green !important');
```

```css
h1 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test text</h1>
```

By the way, I am only using `addRule` for compatability with older versions of Internet Explorer. I am aware that `insertRule` is a more robust function.

Comment: in this case there are no stylesheets.... (so your snippet won't work at all here...)

Comment: @CayceK I have verified with developer tools that this does not work when a stylesheet is present. I added a stylesheet to my code snippet above.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle with a stylesheet added.](http://jsfiddle.net/xo1oyp4d/)  This is curious, because I know I've done this [exact thing](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) before.

Comment: So I could submit another answer or I could just copy @bishop. Basically he is right. I don't ever use `!important` so I didn't realize this basic fact right away. You are using `!important` incorrectly. HOWEVER. You are also using the `addRule` when you should instead use `insertRule`.This will help you override css styles that you want to override without using `!important`. see http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

Comment: @CayceK True that.  The David Walsh article is a great resource for this!

Comment: @bishop sadly I didn't read your whole comment so good point! I guess I just reiterate all you're saying any way!! I stumbled on it when I searched `addRule` never heard of this use case before...

Comment: @CayceK It's hard to see the link in my comment, thanks for including it in your comment AND for pointing out this "important" point!

Comment: I realized shortly after posting the question that `body` doesn't override `h1` even if I do it in the CSS. I suppose I am losing out in the specificity (h1 vs body), even though `!important` does affect the actual cascade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `!important` bubbles like you're expecting.  `!important` lets rules take precedence over other rules with the same selector.  Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xo1oyp4d/8/):

```
<style>
#me { color:blue !important; }
</style>
<p id='me'>Hello, World</p>
<script>
sheet.addRule('#me','color: green !important;');
</script>
```

You'll notice that `#me` should be blue by the stylesheet, but it's being overriden by the `addRule`.

In your example, you're saying you want body color to percolate down to paragraphs, but `!important` is about choosing between rules with the same selector, not hierarchy. [CSS Tricks has some words on this.](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: After some tests, I think that the selector specificity is the problem, instead of `!important` being stripped. It seems important *does not* allow a less specific selector to override a more specific one.

Comment: The really subtle difference that fixed it was to use the same selector for `addRule` as was used in the CSS. Here's a fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xo1oyp4d/14/ where I added `!important` to the page's CSS so I could check that it was properly overridden.

Comment: @AlexW: Glad it's fixed!  For future passerbys, here's what [MDN has to say on Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in the technical sense.